# Update unable to run with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a query below that attempts to try to update the record of my database. and I am unable to run it and an error was shown:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery

Change the status of all bikes which have been reported faulty more than 6 times in January 2018 and set the bike status to "C".

Updated my SQL command:

```
UPDATE Bike 
SET Status = 'C'
SELECT b.Status 
FROM Bike b
INNER JOIN Fault ft ON b.BikeID = ft.BikeID
INNER JOIN Feedback fb ON ft.FBID = fb.FBID
WHERE ((COUNT(fb.FBID) > 6) 
  AND (DATEPART(YEAR, fb.FbDateTIME) = 2018)
  AND (DATENAME(MONTH, fb.FbDateTIME) = 'January'))
```

Contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

As I am new to SQL, I am not really sure how to make a subquery equivalent of this and can anybody help me with this? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Aggregate` function in `Where` clause. You need to use `Having` clause to filter the groups. Try something like this

```
UPDATE b
SET    Status = 'C'
FROM   Bike b
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Fault ft
                      INNER JOIN Feedback fb
                              ON ft.FBID = fb.FBID
               WHERE  b.BikeID = ft.BikeID
                      AND fb.FbDateTIME >= '2018-01-01'
                      AND fb.FbDateTIME < '2018-02-01'
               HAVING Count(fb.FBID) > 6)
```

**Note :** To filter the `Jan 2018` records, I prefer to use this `fb.FbDateTIME >= '2018-01-01' AND fb.FbDateTIME < '2018-02-01'` method. Using `DATEPART` function in `Where` clause will make the query non sargable

Answer (score 0):

Move the COUNT(1) to having

```
UPDATE B
SET Status = 'C'
FROM Bike b
INNER JOIN Fault ft ON b.BikeID = ft.BikeID
INNER JOIN Feedback fb ON ft.FBID = fb.FBID
WHERE (
  AND (DATEPART(YEAR, fb.FbDateTIME) = 2018)
  AND (DATENAME(MONTH, fb.FbDateTIME) = 'January'))
HAVING (COUNT(fb.FBID) > 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have incorrect syntax of `UPDATE` statement after `SET Status= 'C'` `SELECT` statement is not valid and the aggregate function in `WHERE` is not allowed so, after these corrections you can use subquery to achieve your desired output as below:

```
UPDATE Bike SET Status= 'C'
FROM Bike b
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT b.BikeID 
            FROM Bike b
            INNER JOIN Fault ft ON b.BikeID=ft.BikeID
            INNER JOIN Feedback fb ON ft.FBID=fb.FBID
            WHERE (DATEPART(YEAR,fb.FbDateTIME)= 2018)
            AND (DATENAME(MONTH,fb.FbDateTIME)= 'January')
            GROUP BY BikeID HAVING (COUNT(fb.FBID)>6)) c ON c.bikeID = b.bikeID
```